# Extending OData deserializer

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am implementing OData v3 API endpoint using ASP.NET Web API.

I noticed that CreateLink method in my Web API is only called when clients do SetLink for an existing entry.

On the other hand, if I am creating a new entry with a link (SetLink), CreateLink on my Web API is not called. Instead, link is included in POST request that creates the entity:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
    <entry xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\" xmlns:d=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices\" xmlns:m=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata\">
        <category term=\"TestProject.Entities.TestEntity\" scheme=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme\" />
        <link rel=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/TestEntityChild\" type=\"application/atom+xml;type=entry\" title=\"TestEntityChild\" href=\"http://localhost:18995/odata/TestEntityChildren(2)\" />
        <id />
        <title />
        <updated>2015-03-05T08:28:05Z</updated>
        <author>
            <name />
        </author>
        <content type=\"application/xml\">
            <m:properties>
                <d:Id m:type=\"Edm.Int32\">0</d:Id>
                <d:OtherProperty m:type=\"Edm.Int32\" m:null=\"true\" />
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
```

How can I bind this link to the model that gets passed to the action of my ODataController?

My first idea was to extend OData deserializer. I was unable to do so due to the fact that ODataEntityDeserializer is internal class. Maybe there is some easier way?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend odata deserialization by adding formatters in WebAPIConfig.cs.

```
    public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        HttpServer APIServer = new HttpServer(config);

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.MaxDepth = 2048;
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

        config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new CustomExceptionHandler());
        var odataFormatters = ODataMediaTypeFormatters.Create(new ODataSerialzer(), new ODataDeserialzer());
        config.Formatters.Clear();
        config.Formatters.AddRange(odataFormatters);

        config.MapODataServiceRoute(routeName: "OData",
            routePrefix: "",
            model: APIConfiguration.GetModel(),
            batchHandler: new DefaultODataBatchHandler(APIServer));
    }

}
```